# How to implement Google Translate API in meteor app

Tags: meteor, google-translate, google-translator-toolkit

I m new to Meteor and i want to create an application that will help to convert my user inputs in different language using google translate api.
Is there any packages for that?

Can anyone help me for this?

Thanks

Comment: why don't you google your question

Comment: i googled and they give me this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-translate and do't know the implementation in meteor application.

Comment: There are others also try out those that you understand.

Comment: can you suggest links?

Comment: you could use the instructions in [https://support.google.com/translate/answer/2534601?hl=en]

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you already found a [npm package](http://npmjs.com/package/google-translate) for `Google Translate`. There are several ways you can use npm packages with Meteor.

[Meteor 1.3 *early beta*](https://forums.meteor.com/t/meteor-1-3-early-beta-now-available) supports npm. If you want a quick example of this, [here](https://forums.meteor.com/t/how-to-setup-meteor-1-3-beta-react-react-router-via-npm/) it is. However, take note that this is **early beta**.

If you are using a stable release (eg. Meteor 1.2), you can use https://atmospherejs.com/meteorhacks/npm.

[Google Translate API is a paid service](https://cloud.google.com/translate/v2/pricing) so I wasn't able to provide a working example for you. Good luck!